# How to change space between columns of text in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word file with text organized as columns. How to change space between columns of text in word 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose the "More Columns" option. Under "Width and Spacing", change the "Spacing" value as you wish.

[image]